# How to import JavaFX 2 project created from netbeans 7.2 in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, javafx-2, netbeans-7

I want to use Eclipse to develop JavaFX. I am trying to import a JavaFX 2 application created in Netbeans 7.2 into Eclipse. But Javafx 2 uses its own Ant build syntax. So when I try to import this Ant project into Eclipse I get the following error:

```
Specified build file does not contain a javac task
```

How do I solve this error? I know there are JavaFX plugins for Eclipse, but I haven't been able to find any that solves my problem. Or do I need to try something else?

Comment: You can just copy sources and use efxclipse.org for Eclipse.

Comment: @SergeyGrinev : How can I make Java FXML application with this plugin in eclipse? Kindly help

Comment: 2 options below **New JavaFX project**, you can find the **New FXML Document** option which will load the default template with the root option you have set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open http://efxclipse.org/install.html, scroll down to "*In Eclipse 4.2 for the adventurous*".

After you have configured properly by setting the path for JavaFX SDK from Window->Preferences, create a new JavaFX project (File->New->Other->JavaFX->JavaFX Project)

Right click on your projet->Import->File System->Select the top level of your NetBeans created project folder-> Select src folder,build.xml, manifest.mf and any other FXML files you wish to import.

For a distributable standalone executable JAR, refer to http://www.efxclipse.org/tut2.html. If you face any problem in Step 11- Click on the "ant build.xml and run" Link in the Build section of the editor, then goto `Window->Preferences->Ant->Runtime->Global Entries->Add External JAR->(Browse to your JDK lib folder) Add tools.jar`.

If your Build still fails and shows this error ->

> BUILD FAILED C:\Workspace\eclipseFx\AppOne\build\build.xml:82:
>   Problem: failed to create task or type
>   javafx:com.sun.javafx.tools.ant:resources

It means ${java.home} is pointing to the JRE and can access jfxrt.jar but fails to access ant-javafx.jar. Find the absolute path for ant-javafx.jar in your JDK and edit that line in build.xml and it should build fine. This error has been fixed in the Nightly Build.

P.S. - You can also create JavaFX RCP applications now. Eclipse 4 Applications can use JavaFX as the rendering technology instead of SWT.

Comment: i am not able to find option to set JavaFX SDK option ??? did you tried it..??? (File->New->Other->JavaFX->JavaFX Project)

Comment: If Eclipse found JavaFX SDK at its default location, then the set JavaFX-SDK-Directory option under preferences won't show.  If you can find the JavaFX Project option, then it must be functioning correctly.

Comment: I am able to import project.. but what about building and running the application .. is it possible to run standalone application of javafx through eclipse as we do in the netbeans ????

Comment: If you are talking about standalone executable JARs, I just edited my answer. If you are talking about an Eclipse 4 Application, here is the tutorial - http://www.efxclipse.org/tut4.html

Comment: Just noticed your error in a different system, it was because tools.jar was not included in Global Entries for Ant Runtime.